# How to setup index.routing.allocation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

How an I setup the `index.routing.allocation.*` settings eg.:

```
PUT test/_settings
{
  "index.routing.allocation.include.size": "big,medium"
}
```

for a `test` index with Java API?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
.put("index.routing.allocation.include.size", "big,medium")
.build();

client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("test")
.setSettings(settings)
.execute().actionGet()
```